# SIP me@domain.com vs (123) 456-7890

Tags: voip, sip, pstn, uri

I'm trying to understand SIP, and one thing that keeps confusing me is phone numbers and dialing plans vs SIP URI's like `me@domain.com`. What is the difference? How do they coexist/work together?

For example, do you connect using a me@domain.com URI and then send DTMF tones over that connection (I doubt it but I'm not sure how else that works?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phone numbers and "SIP URIs like `me@domain.com`" are different kinds of URIs. A phone number can be represented as a URI like this:

```
tel:+12125551212
```

whereas a "SIP URI like `me@domain.com`" can be represented as a URI like this:

```
sip:me@domain.com
```

Many SIP user agents don't actually use [`tel:` URIs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt). Instead they just take the number that the user dialed and stick into a SIP URI as the local-part and use the configured proxy server as the host-part, like this:

```
sip:12125551212@my-sip-proxy.example.com
```

`sip:` URIs can be used directly to route a call over an IP network: just lookup the host-part of the SIP URI in DNS and forward the call to the location you find in the NAPTR/SRV/A/AAAA records.

`tel:` URIs must be routed according to rules configured in the SIP proxy. Examples of such rules could be:

- Send the call over a circuit-switched PSTN channel to the phone number given in the URI
- Forward the call to another SIP proxy, after possibly translating the phone number or even changing the URI from a `tel:` URI to a `sip:` URI.
- Look up the phone number in DNS under [`e164.arpa`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2916.txt) and translate the URI as per the NAPTR records found there.

All of this is unrelated to sending DTMF tones through a call. That can only happen after a call is established, and the SIP proxies, switches, and routers on the signaling path generally won't pay any attention to them (they're just media content, even if they're represented as [RFC2833](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2833) events rather than as audio).

Comment: Ok, that seems to help clear things up. Just to make sure I understand right, the only place SIP uses a telephone number is by using a proxy to get it into the PSTN network.

Comment: No: sending a call that is dailed to a phone number is common bu not necessary: even if it's a phone number it doesn't mean it's going to go to the PSTN. For example, you can find my phone number in DNS under `e164.org` and that tells you how to route the call to me over the Internet without using the PSTN. Essentially the NAPTR record you find under `e164.org` tells you how to translate the phone number (`tel:` URI) to a `sip:` URI.